# Firefox 100: CSS 3D Transform rotateY(180deg) and SVG not playing well together

Tags: css, svg, firefox, css-transitions, css-transforms

This *may* be a browser-bug relating to how **Firefox Desktop 100.0.2.** handles **SVG** and **CSS Transforms**.

Or else I'm doing something wrong to bring about this undesired effect.

- I have a `<button>` containing two **SVG**s, one `positioned` on top of the other.
- The **SVG** on the bottom is rotated 180 degrees (using `transform: rotateY(180deg)`) and invisible (using `opacity: 0`).
- When the `<button>` is clicked, both **SVG**s rotate and at the halfway point in the rotation, the **SVG** on the bottom becomes visible and the **SVG** on the top becomes invisible.

The overall effect is that the `<button>` image rotates and transforms in the middle of its rotation.

> *Why is messing about with `opacity` necessary when we have `backface-visibility`?*
>
> Because **iOS Safari** doesn't support `backface-visibility`.

**What's the issue?**

The issue is that this isn't a clean rotation. The SVG which suddenly becomes visible turns into a blurry mess - like when the helicopter pilot in the original **The Matrix** is possessed by one of the agents - before settling into its new shape.

Click the button several times below to see this undesired effect in action. (I've slowed the transition down a little, so you have more time to see it in action.)

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const audioButton = document.querySelector('.audioButton');
const audioOn = document.querySelector('.audio-on');
const audioOff = document.querySelector('.audio-off');

const toggleAudio = (e) => {
  audioOn.classList.toggle('active');
  audioOff.classList.toggle('active');
}

audioButton.addEventListener('click', toggleAudio, false);
```

```css
.audioButton {
  position: relative;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(219, 76%, 50%), hsl(219, 80%, 43%) 50%, hsl(219, 81%, 41%) 51%, hsl(219, 88%, 33%));
  border: 2px solid hsl(220, 100%, 25%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(220, 100%, 26%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.audioButton::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.audioButton:hover::after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.audioButtonVector {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition: transform 1.2s linear, opacity 0s linear 0.6s;
}

.audio-off {
  color: rgb(91, 127, 239);
}

.audio-on {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.active {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="audioButton" type="button" title="Turn Audio On">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       lang="en-GB"
       class="audioButtonVector audio-off active"
       viewBox="0 0 768 768">
  
    <title>Mute Icon</title>
  
    <defs><style><![CDATA[path {fill: currentColor;}]]></style></defs>
  
    <path d="m 514.64857,746.41567 c -7.23403,-2.33279 -15.45533,-6.93789 -23.16845,-12.97761 -3.14331,-2.46136 -44.6698,-43.2877 -92.2811,-90.7252 l -86.56599,-86.25 h -67.29941 c -47.65888,0 -68.66895,-0.33827 -71.99223,-1.1591 -10.38521,-2.56509 -23.41546,-14.17469 -26.78831,-23.86766 -1.83792,-5.28188 -1.90451,-10.42057 -1.90451,-146.97324 v -141.5 l 2.89186,-6.2618 c 3.2572,-7.05289 8.40912,-12.23957 15.39549,-15.4994 2.59196,-1.20939 4.91571,-2.33594 5.16389,-2.50342 0.24818,-0.16749 -20.72025,-21.55146 -46.5965,-47.51995 -30.937231,-31.04751 -47.695971,-48.58514 -48.940811,-51.21543 -2.8746,-6.0739 -2.65973,-18.56296 0.42151,-24.500003 3.16419,-6.09687 8.64277,-11.63242 14.66456,-14.81707 4.20155,-2.222 6.27753,-2.64426 13.000001,-2.64426 6.74443,0 8.78473,0.4178 13,2.6621 3.65377,1.94535 22.6348,20.316143 70.49714,68.230673 l 65.49713,65.56856 h 31.48475 31.48474 l 89.51812,-89.32184 c 95.1437,-94.935093 95.62848,-95.37672 110.05601,-100.257898 6.53075,-2.209511 8.73786,-2.420265 25.34601,-2.420265 16.8774,0 18.51482,0.162627 22.65421,2.25 3.53889,1.784556 5.02413,3.387752 7.17979,7.75 l 2.71791,5.5 0.0321,248.502843 0.0321,248.50284 65.8925,65.88683 c 46.80175,46.79773 66.57555,67.22255 68.25005,70.49716 3.3554,6.56182 3.366,18.66705 0.022,25.11033 -3.1642,6.09686 -8.6428,11.63242 -14.6646,14.81707 -6.9012,3.64972 -18.7705,3.80022 -25.50001,0.32333 -3.02072,-1.5607 -19.21059,-17.00386 -49.25,-46.97853 l -44.75005,-44.65354 v 56.77796 c 0,62.53583 0.17139,60.72201 -6.27221,66.37956 -4.82954,4.24039 -10.80361,5.3457 -28.52701,5.27798 -11.68868,-0.0447 -15.93014,-0.4526 -20.70078,-1.99102 z" />
  
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       lang="en-GB"
       class="audioButtonVector audio-on"
       viewBox="0 0 768 768">
  
    <title>Audio Icon</title>
    
    <defs><style><![CDATA[path {fill: currentColor;}]]></style></defs>
  
    <path d="m 470.57734,741.2876 c -7.71475,-2.83606 -11.18777,-4.89195 -18.82603,-11.1443 -2.39807,-1.96296 -43.79807,-42.82236 -92,-90.79868 l -87.63988,-87.22967 -69.5,-0.27033 -69.5,-0.27033 -5.86156,-2.87813 c -8.69995,-4.27183 -19.79481,-15.53374 -22.7789,-23.12187 l -2.35954,-6 v -138 c 0,-131.11094 0.0914,-138.27456 1.83191,-143.5 4.32786,-12.99369 11.24782,-19.42452 26.95392,-25.04871 l 8.21417,-2.94141 66.47695,-0.005 66.47696,-0.005 90.52304,-90.2663 c 95.08695,-94.817141 94.44763,-94.232081 108.57699,-99.360761 5.97505,-2.16883 8.09265,-2.37282 24.63202,-2.37282 16.6968,0 18.4388,0.17171 22.54471,2.2223 2.44735,1.22227 5.35455,3.49301 6.46044,5.04609 4.95602,6.96009 4.73518,-9.62279 4.77327,358.416511 0.0249,240.3642 -0.28452,345.03405 -1.02571,347 -0.58374,1.54831 -2.49624,4.31599 -4.25,6.15042 -5.99091,6.26644 -7.33614,6.60106 -27.68867,6.88738 -18.04936,0.25392 -18.68352,0.19279 -26.03409,-2.50939 z M 600.3594,549.70163 c -5.93421,-2.20326 -10.33035,-6.14828 -13.14459,-11.79572 -5.39826,-10.83291 -3.08865,-16.71172 11.68289,-29.73724 40.36186,-35.59104 59.79177,-80.99428 57.38451,-134.09438 -2.23918,-49.39231 -20.58907,-87.5315 -58.17881,-120.9213 -12.02899,-10.68498 -14.65864,-14.55603 -14.65864,-21.5787 0,-11.90939 13.04063,-24.61151 23.75911,-23.14238 6.3213,0.86643 9.17103,2.59906 20.69094,12.58013 39.46289,34.19135 62.29527,76.84757 69.88539,130.56225 1.92863,13.64871 1.60428,48.41306 -0.58777,63 -5.75409,38.29032 -20.26693,71.24453 -44.36153,100.73141 -8.21433,10.05267 -30.26582,31.0853 -34.9257,33.312 -4.92676,2.35423 -12.81232,2.84138 -17.5458,1.08393 z" />
  
  </svg>

</button>
```

---

**Nota Bene:**

I note that I if I change the `transition` from:

- `transition: transform 1.2s linear, opacity 0s linear 0.6s;`

to:

- `transition: transform 1.2s linear, opacity 0.2s linear 0.5s;`

the bizarre effect is minimised.

Using *magic numbers* like this, isn't an ideal compromise, I'll fall back to that if I can't get to the bottom of the issue.

---

### A Significant Improvement:

I recalled some advice about sometimes needing to put different transitions on different elements. The updated version below **is a clear improvement** in that if you keep the mouse cursor hovered over the button after you click, the rotation is clean.

But if you move the mouse cursor off the button after clicking, the same messy effect is still visible.

**Improved Working Example:**

```js
const audioButton = document.querySelector('.audioButton');
const audioOn = document.querySelector('.audio-on');
const audioOff = document.querySelector('.audio-off');

const toggleAudio = (e) => {
  audioOn.classList.toggle('active');
  audioOff.classList.toggle('active');
}

audioButton.addEventListener('click', toggleAudio, false);
```

```css
.audioButton {
  position: relative;
  width: 52px;
  height: 52px;
  margin: 0 12px 0 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(219, 76%, 50%), hsl(219, 80%, 43%) 50%, hsl(219, 81%, 41%) 51%, hsl(219, 88%, 33%));
  border: 2px solid hsl(220, 100%, 25%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid hsl(220, 100%, 26%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer; 
}

.audioButton::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.audioButton:hover::after {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.audioButtonVector {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: transform 0.6s linear;
}

.audioButtonVector.active {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

.audioButtonVector path {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0s linear 0.3s;
}

.audioButtonVector.active path {
  opacity: 1;
}

.audio-off {
  color: rgb(91, 127, 239);
}

.audio-on {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<button class="audioButton" type="button" title="Turn Audio On">

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       lang="en-GB"
       class="audioButtonVector audio-off active"
       viewBox="0 0 768 768">
  
    <title>Mute Icon</title>
  
    <defs><style><![CDATA[path {fill: currentColor;}]]></style></defs>
  
    <path d="m 514.64857,746.41567 c -7.23403,-2.33279 -15.45533,-6.93789 -23.16845,-12.97761 -3.14331,-2.46136 -44.6698,-43.2877 -92.2811,-90.7252 l -86.56599,-86.25 h -67.29941 c -47.65888,0 -68.66895,-0.33827 -71.99223,-1.1591 -10.38521,-2.56509 -23.41546,-14.17469 -26.78831,-23.86766 -1.83792,-5.28188 -1.90451,-10.42057 -1.90451,-146.97324 v -141.5 l 2.89186,-6.2618 c 3.2572,-7.05289 8.40912,-12.23957 15.39549,-15.4994 2.59196,-1.20939 4.91571,-2.33594 5.16389,-2.50342 0.24818,-0.16749 -20.72025,-21.55146 -46.5965,-47.51995 -30.937231,-31.04751 -47.695971,-48.58514 -48.940811,-51.21543 -2.8746,-6.0739 -2.65973,-18.56296 0.42151,-24.500003 3.16419,-6.09687 8.64277,-11.63242 14.66456,-14.81707 4.20155,-2.222 6.27753,-2.64426 13.000001,-2.64426 6.74443,0 8.78473,0.4178 13,2.6621 3.65377,1.94535 22.6348,20.316143 70.49714,68.230673 l 65.49713,65.56856 h 31.48475 31.48474 l 89.51812,-89.32184 c 95.1437,-94.935093 95.62848,-95.37672 110.05601,-100.257898 6.53075,-2.209511 8.73786,-2.420265 25.34601,-2.420265 16.8774,0 18.51482,0.162627 22.65421,2.25 3.53889,1.784556 5.02413,3.387752 7.17979,7.75 l 2.71791,5.5 0.0321,248.502843 0.0321,248.50284 65.8925,65.88683 c 46.80175,46.79773 66.57555,67.22255 68.25005,70.49716 3.3554,6.56182 3.366,18.66705 0.022,25.11033 -3.1642,6.09686 -8.6428,11.63242 -14.6646,14.81707 -6.9012,3.64972 -18.7705,3.80022 -25.50001,0.32333 -3.02072,-1.5607 -19.21059,-17.00386 -49.25,-46.97853 l -44.75005,-44.65354 v 56.77796 c 0,62.53583 0.17139,60.72201 -6.27221,66.37956 -4.82954,4.24039 -10.80361,5.3457 -28.52701,5.27798 -11.68868,-0.0447 -15.93014,-0.4526 -20.70078,-1.99102 z" />
  
  </svg>

  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       lang="en-GB"
       class="audioButtonVector audio-on"
       viewBox="0 0 768 768">
  
    <title>Audio Icon</title>
    
    <defs><style><![CDATA[path {fill: currentColor;}]]></style></defs>
  
    <path d="m 470.57734,741.2876 c -7.71475,-2.83606 -11.18777,-4.89195 -18.82603,-11.1443 -2.39807,-1.96296 -43.79807,-42.82236 -92,-90.79868 l -87.63988,-87.22967 -69.5,-0.27033 -69.5,-0.27033 -5.86156,-2.87813 c -8.69995,-4.27183 -19.79481,-15.53374 -22.7789,-23.12187 l -2.35954,-6 v -138 c 0,-131.11094 0.0914,-138.27456 1.83191,-143.5 4.32786,-12.99369 11.24782,-19.42452 26.95392,-25.04871 l 8.21417,-2.94141 66.47695,-0.005 66.47696,-0.005 90.52304,-90.2663 c 95.08695,-94.817141 94.44763,-94.232081 108.57699,-99.360761 5.97505,-2.16883 8.09265,-2.37282 24.63202,-2.37282 16.6968,0 18.4388,0.17171 22.54471,2.2223 2.44735,1.22227 5.35455,3.49301 6.46044,5.04609 4.95602,6.96009 4.73518,-9.62279 4.77327,358.416511 0.0249,240.3642 -0.28452,345.03405 -1.02571,347 -0.58374,1.54831 -2.49624,4.31599 -4.25,6.15042 -5.99091,6.26644 -7.33614,6.60106 -27.68867,6.88738 -18.04936,0.25392 -18.68352,0.19279 -26.03409,-2.50939 z M 600.3594,549.70163 c -5.93421,-2.20326 -10.33035,-6.14828 -13.14459,-11.79572 -5.39826,-10.83291 -3.08865,-16.71172 11.68289,-29.73724 40.36186,-35.59104 59.79177,-80.99428 57.38451,-134.09438 -2.23918,-49.39231 -20.58907,-87.5315 -58.17881,-120.9213 -12.02899,-10.68498 -14.65864,-14.55603 -14.65864,-21.5787 0,-11.90939 13.04063,-24.61151 23.75911,-23.14238 6.3213,0.86643 9.17103,2.59906 20.69094,12.58013 39.46289,34.19135 62.29527,76.84757 69.88539,130.56225 1.92863,13.64871 1.60428,48.41306 -0.58777,63 -5.75409,38.29032 -20.26693,71.24453 -44.36153,100.73141 -8.21433,10.05267 -30.26582,31.0853 -34.9257,33.312 -4.92676,2.35423 -12.81232,2.84138 -17.5458,1.08393 z" />
  
  </svg>

</button>
```

---

### No Further Improvement:

In the past I've seen issues in **iOS Safari** related to **CSS 3D Rotations**.

So I've replaced:

- `transform: rotateY(180deg)`
- `transform: rotateY(0deg)`

with:

- `transform: scale(-1, 1)`
- `transform: scale(1, 1)`

The minimal flicker that was previously visible in **iOS Safari** (I didn't mention this before - it's an unrelated issue) has now gone.

But the CSS update above hasn't made any significant difference to the undesired visual effect in **Firefox Desktop**.

Comment: Which browser(s) are you seeing this on?  The animation works fine in Chrome/Win.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau  - Thanks. That's encouraging. I'm seeing this in **Firefox Desktop 100.0.2**.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1686654 may have fixed this. Can you try a Firefox nightly?

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. I'll check it out on Firefox Nightly. In the meantime, I've ascertained the issue has something to do with the _focus_ of the mouse cursor (though I'm not sure what, exactly). I've substantially minimised the issue by giving the `<button>` a style of `pointer-events: none` (which means the  `<button>` can never have _focus_) and then applying `:hover` styles and `click` interactivity to the `<button>` via the parent element.